# Vue.js listen event only when top

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-handling, vue-component, keypress

I have built a custom pin code input Vue component for touch screen, which doesn't have any real input but buttons. I have customizable key map in my code and for desktop use I'd like to have possibility to use normal keyboard for input, too.

However, when I have multiple pin inputs e.g. in page and in modal top of it, the keystrokes will of course hit into every component because I have all of those mounted.

So I'm trying to find a way to have only currently focused component taking the keyboard input. Components own buttons on touch screen are working correctly, there isn't any problem.

```js
...

data() {
    return {
        value: '',
        keys: [
            { name: '9', code: 'Digit9'},
            { name: '8', code: 'Digit8'},
            { name: '7', code: 'Digit7'},
            { name: '6', code: 'Digit6'},
            { name: '5', code: 'Digit5'},
            { name: '4', code: 'Digit4'},
            { name: '3', code: 'Digit3'},
            { name: '2', code: 'Digit2'},
            { name: '1', code: 'Digit1'},
            { name: '0', code: 'Digit0'},
        ]
    };
},

mounted() {
    window.addEventListener("keypress", e => {
        let result = _.find(this.keys, ['code', e.code]); // Lodash
        if (result) this.value = "" + this.value + result.name;
    });
}

...
```

[image: PIN code input]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the wrapper of your component is a div, you can add `tabindex` attribute, so the div can receive `keypress` event

And then you can add `keypress` event to `this.$el` instead of global window

```
Vue.component('greeting', {
  template: '<div tabindex="1">Welcome to coligo!</div>',
  props: ['name'],
  mounted() {
    this.$el.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
      console.log(this.name, e)
    })
  },
  methods: {
  }
});

// create a new Vue instance and mount it to our div element above with the id of app
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/ittus/6b2ru73t/